# How to add single quotes to the items in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I am learning python. I was trying to add the  quotes to the items in the list but during the list append quotes are added only to the beginning and end of the list.  Is there anyway i can add quotes to all the  items in list ? any help would be appreciated in learning process.

import subprocess
import os
from tabulate import tabulate

```
destination_list = ['google www.google.com 443','github www.github.com 443']
op = []


for i in destination_list:
    str_split = i.split(" ")
    nc_output = subprocess.call(["nc","-zvw","5",str_split[1],str_split[2]])
    if (nc_output == 0):
            op.append([str_split[0]+", "+str_split[1]+", "+"Success"])
    else:
            op.append([str_split[0]+", "+str_split[1]+", "+"Failed"])
print (op)
```

output:

```
[['google, www.google.com, Success'], ['github, www.github.com, Failed']]
```

Expected_output:

Thank You

```
[['google', 'www.google.com', 'Success'], ['github', 'www.github.com', 'Failed']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't concatenate your strings, push a list into `op`.

```
op.append([str_split[0], str_split[1], "Success"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by appending the result to the first two elements in `str_split` list *and* simplify your code by using a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) as shown below:

```
for i in destination_list:
    str_split = i.split()
    nc_output = subprocess.call(["nc", "-zvw", "5", str_split[1], str_split[2]])
    op.append(str_split[:2] + ["Failed" if nc_output == 0 else "Success"])
```

Also note that this isn't really adding quotes to the strings, that's just how they they're printed.